# When I connect a battery, the system fails

Tags: power, batteries, power-electronics, solar-cell, matlab

I have a standalone PV system with boost converter using perturb and observe (P&O) as the MPP algorithm.

The values of input, output capacitors, inductor are calculated correctly based upon a research paper.

The PV panel rating is 6820W and the load is a DC resistor.

The input power from the panel stays nearly at MPP when the battery is not connected, but when I attach a 12V battery in parallel to the load resistance to store the energy at load side, the entire system crumbles.  The input power from panel keeps oscillating from positive to negative power levels, the battery discharges instead of getting charged.

What might be the issue?

Comment: more info needed

Comment: What is the voltage of the panel without battery? 6820 W at 12 V would be 568 A, the current is pretty high. 48 V and 142 A looks better. What is the load resistance by the way?